Elements of finite order in the group of invertible affine transformations
Sorry if it is elenentary but here it goes:
Let $(G,\circ,id)$ be the group of invertible affine transformations with composition i.e the collection of all $f =ax+b \in G$ $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that $a \neq 0$ and $id(x) =x$. Does $G$ have elements of finite order?
Can only think of $f(x)=-x$ the element besides the identity such that $f^{n}=id$ for all even $n$.
Are there any other possible elements of finite order? What may happen if I substitute $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$?
Thanks in advance.

The elements of finite order are the identity and the reflections $f(x) = -x + b$. Over $\mathbb{C}$ you get rotations of finite order about any point in the plane.

Hint If $f$ has order $n$, then $$f^n(x) = a (a (\cdots (a x + b) + \cdots) + b) + b = a^n x + (a^{n - 1} + \cdots + a + 1) b = x ,$$ that is,

$a^n = 1$, i.e., $a$ is an $n$th root of unity, and
$(a^{n - 1} + \cdots + a + 1) b = 0$.


 Now, if $a = 1$, then $f(x) = x + n b$, hence $b = 0$, so $f$ is actually the identity function, which has order $1$.  But if $a \neq 1$, then $a^{n - 1} + \cdots + a + 1 = \frac{a^n - 1}{a - 1} = 0$, so $f^{n}(x) = x$ as desired. Hence, if we denote $\zeta := \exp \frac{2\pi i}{n}$, the transformations having order dividing $n$ are the identity and the maps $$x \mapsto \zeta^m x + b, \qquad m \in \{1, \ldots, n - 1\}, \quad b \in \Bbb C .$$ These maps are respectively anticlockwise rotations by $\frac{2 \pi m}{n}$ around the points $\frac{b}{1 - \zeta^m}$. Those having order exactly $n$ are those for which $\zeta^m$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, that is, for which $\operatorname{gcd}(n, m) = 1$. More generally, $x \mapsto \zeta^m x + b$ has order $\frac{n}{\operatorname{gcd}(n, m)}$. The only real roots of unity are $\pm 1$, which restricts the real options substantially.


Try to explicitly write down what it means to have an element of finite order in your group:
Then, you will see that
$$a(a(\ldots(ax+b)\ldots)+b) + b = x$$
This is then equivalent to $a^n\cdot x +(a^{n - 1} + \cdots + a + 1) b = x$.
From here, you get conditions on $a$ and $b$, namely $a^n = 1$ and $(a^{n - 1} + \cdots + a + 1) b= 0$.
Depending on whether you are working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ gives you different solutions, i.e. for $\mathbb{R}$ you get reflections ($a$ = -1) and the identity ($a$ = 1) and for $\mathbb{C}$ you get rotations depending on the $n$-th root of unity you choose as your $a$.

Are you sure about your "equivalent to" equation?

Your calculation is incorrect. For example, applying it three times gives $x\mapsto ax+b \mapsto a(ax+b) +b = a^2x+ab+b\mapsto a(a^2x+ab+b)+b = a^3x+a^2b+ab+b$, and not $a^3x+a^2b+b$, as you claim.

This calculation can be avoided. You can instead argue that if $a \neq 1$ then there is a unique fixed point and just translate so that this fixed point is the origin.
